# TYPO3 Page Type "External Link" as popup

Tags: typo3, external-links

i have a page from the type "external link" and i want to open this into a popup window with a special size.

I know, that i can use the "target" option in the general tab to open the link in a external window - but i want a popup window, see the part above.

Have anyone a tip for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it should be possible to write the typolink function parameters in the target field.

So you can easily write the following code in the target input to open the link in a popup..

```
500x600
```

I've tested it on TYPO3 6.2 .. It is working

[image: Put code in target input]